# Getting wrong access token from registerCallback method of facebook LoginButton

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I can successfully log into facebook by calling this signIn() method.

```kotlin
private fun signIn() {
        loginBtn?.registerCallback(callBackManager,object: FacebookCallback<LoginResult>{
            override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {
                handleFacebookAccessToken(result!!.accessToken)
            }

            override fun onCancel() {

            }

            override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
                Log.d("MainActivity:", "onError "+error?.message)
            }

        })
    }

    private fun handleFacebookAccessToken(accessToken: AccessToken?) {
        val authCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken!!.token)
        firebaseAuth?.signInWithCredential(authCredential)
            ?.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d("MainActivity:", "signInWithCredential:success")
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w("dsds", "signInWithCredential:failure ", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
    }
```

But I am not able to authenticate with firebase to sign into firebase by calling handleFacebookAccessToken(accessToken: AccessToken?) method because it is giving invalid access token.
If I manually get an access token from a test user by going to the app in facebook developer console and
hardcode it in the handleFacebookAccessToken(token: String?) method below then it works.

```kotlin
private fun handleFacebookAccessToken(token: String?) {
        val authCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token)
        firebaseAuth?.signInWithCredential(authCredential)
            ?.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d("MainActivity:", "signInWithCredential:success")
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w("dsds", "signInWithCredential:failure ", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
    }
```

I am getting this exception below.

```kotlin
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Remote site 5XX from facebook.com for VERIFY_CREDENTIAL ]
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztt.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.4:28)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvb.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.4:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvc.zzk(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.4:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuz.zzh(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.4:25)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztq.zzk(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.4:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzpr.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.4:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvg.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.4:25)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuq.zzd(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.4:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzpy.zzc(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.4:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztu.zzd(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.4:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzsg.zzd(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.4:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzsf.accept(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zacj.doExecute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaf.zac(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zac(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:167)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:139)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:105)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:145)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.base.zar.dispatchMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:8)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Comment: have you setup App ID and App Secret correctly? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login#kotlin+ktx

Comment: Yes. Even if I generate access token from a test user in developer console and hardcode it in the code it works fine but the access token I am getting from the callback method is not working. I verified the access token by passing it in the url below

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}

.The access token is returning the correct test user id even.

Comment: can you check App Type: on your facebook app console? Make sure its listed as "Consumer" - reference https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4524#issuecomment-764610739

Comment: @AmodGokhale you can post your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Select app and confirm App Type is Consumer

[image]

Solution referred from https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4524#issuecomment-764610739